# Axios auto refresh with React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I slowly start my adventure with React and sit on this problem from days, wanted to learn axios So I'm creating movie-library based on Json server package. Everything works pretty fine just I can't make auto refresh after every action like adding editing or deleting new movie. I know I have to somehow pass function getMovie to then section of editMovie, deleteMovie and addMovie but I completely don't know how. I put getMovie into function and pass it to componentDidMount to launch it at the very beginning but I don't know how to pass it to form component to put it into edit/delete/add functions. I tried to do it through export function but didn't work out. probably I gotta do it through props but it also doesn't want to work for me:( I would be super grateful for any help as I'm out of ideas.

Form Component

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            type: '',
            description: '',
            id: '',
            movies: [],
            errors: "",
        }
    }


    handleChangeOne = e => {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleChangeTwo = e => {
        this.setState({
            type: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleChangeThree = e => {
        this.setState({
            description: e.target.value
        })
    }


    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies/`;
        if (this.state.name != "" && this.state.type != "" && this.state.description != "") {
            axios
                .post(url, {
                    name: this.state.name,
                    type: this.state.type,
                    description: this.state.description,
                    id: this.state.id
                })
                .then(res => {
                    // console.log(res);
                    // console.log(res.data);
                    this.setState({
                        movies: [this.state.name, this.state.type, this.state.description, this.state.id]
                    })
                })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                errors:"Please, Fill all forms above"
            })
        }
    }

    handleRemove = e => {
        // const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies/`;
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies/${e.id}`;
        axios
            .delete(url)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }

    editMovie = e => {
        if (this.state.name != "" && this.state.type != "" && this.state.description != "") {
            const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies/${e.id}`;
            axios
                .put(url, {
                    name: this.state.name,
                    type: this.state.type,
                    description: this.state.description,
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                errors:"Please, Fill all forms to edit movie"
            })
        }
    }



    render() {


        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie" onChange={this.handleChangeOne}/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type of movie" onChange={this.handleChangeTwo}/>
                    <textarea placeholder="Description of the movie"
                              onChange={this.handleChangeThree}></textarea>
                    <input id="addMovie" type="submit" value="Add movie" ></input>
                    <p>{this.state.errors}</p>
                </form>
                <List removeClick={this.handleRemove} editClick={this.editMovie}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

List Component

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            movies: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMovie()

    }
     getMovie = () => {
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies`;
        console.log(url);
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                const movies = res.data;
                this.setState({
                    movies: movies,
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    // }




    editMovie = (event, e) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("it works with edit!");
        if (typeof this.props.editClick === "function") {
            this.props.editClick(e)
        } else {
            console.log("Doesn't work with edit");
        }
    }


    removeMovie = (event, e) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("it works with remove!");
        if (typeof this.props.removeClick === "function") {
            this.props.removeClick(e)
        } else {
            console.log("Doesn't work with remove");
        }
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="movieList">
                {this.state.movies.map(e =>
                    <ul>
                        <li data-id={e.id} onClick={event => this.editMovie(event, e)}>
                            Title: {e.name}
                        </li>
                        <li data-id={e.id} onClick={event => this.editMovie(event, e)}>
                            Type: {e.type}
                        </li>
                        <li data-id={e.id} onClick={event => this.editMovie(event, e)}>
                            Description: {e.description}
                        </li>
                        <button className="removeMovie" type="submit" onClick={event => this.removeMovie(event, e)}>Delete</button>
                    </ul>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not refreshing because it is only being called once after the component is fully loaded. What you need is a trigger which executes after an update.

For these, there are lifecycle methods that React exposes.

You should be moving your `getMovie()` method in `componentWillReceiveProps()` or `componentDidUpdate()`.

If you are using the latest react version, you should be using `getDerivedStateFromProps()`.

These three methods will execute everytime you have updated the state. However, these methods are useful in different use cases ( which you'll have to decide )

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for answer:) actually it works more or less good, I mean I used componentDidUpdate() as that was only working method (gotta read more later about others two as I hear about them first time), but it keeps refreshing every second as I an see in console log. I did something similar before with setInterval and effect was same but I guess it's unecessary wasting of resources. I'm beginner so Is it ok it keeps refreshing even when no action is made? Or it rather should launch when I do some action?

Comment: this method is fired after every update made. you have to actually place if conditions in there, to check on which conditions do you actually want to fetch. some may be unecessary

Comment: hmm I understand but in Form component I tried to set conditions like 
`componentDidUpdate() {
if (this.handleRemove() || this.editMovie()) {
            this.getMovie()
        }`
and in return I get error Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: how are functions used as conditionals? Shouldn't you assign a variable for each handler? like a condition for `isRemovedButtonClicked`?

Comment: eh this seems so simple and probably it is but will give me heart attack I guess, sorry friend for many silly questions but I really want to finally handle this React.. Anyway if I remember well in standard js I could do `let removeMovie = (event,e) => {...}` but here it shows errors that it is not possible.
But is this what you mean? To assign variable more or less in that way just correct one? I tried to do `var isRemovedButtonClicked = removeMovie(events) =>{...}`
and then I would put it to `componentDidUpdate() {
if (isRemovedButtonClicked === true) {
this.getMovie()}`

Comment: please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177075/room-for-question-discussion for further discussion

Comment: I have 15 reputation and need 20 to start chatting there... can I text you on slack/fb/email or something other then?

Comment: there, now it's 20?

Comment: I have 20 rep, thanks, also can see what you write there but when I enter to chat I still see notification I can't talk until I have 20 rep... maybe it needs some time to proceed

Comment: click on the link again?

Comment: tried several times and doesn't work, to not prolong it here, I will send a ticket and ask moderators what's going on and when I have access to chat I will let you know